# VBA Excel End If without block If Error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a lite problem with some statement in my code. the situation is like this:
I am working with UserForm in excel based on selection of months and the data goes to my report from another report. To analyze data of certain month we need data of the month before. So for January we need data from last's year database for December. 
I made special sub just in case we need to analyze data about January and we need the old database too. And with that statment I have a problem and I get that error "VBA End If without block If Error" :

```
'If the month that was selected is January then we need to open old Visual file Month
If MonthName = Lists.Range("A2").Value Then 'it means January
    Call January
Else
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "December" Then
            Sheets("December").Delete
            End
        End If
    Next ws
End If
```

Please, can someone help?

Comment: Remove this  End before the End If

Comment: If you mean to Exit then put Exit Sub

Comment: I dont want to exit, just to stop the loop if I found worksheet named "December". @QHarr

Comment: then put  Exit For

Comment: BTW - It is not a good idea to use VBA function names (e.g. `MonthName`) as variable names.  (I don't think that would cause the "End If without block If" error though - that sounds more like one of your `If` statements was written as a single-line `If` but you still wrote an `End If` for it, but your posted code doesn't show that.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Exit For to exit a For Loop.

```
If MonthName = Lists.Range("A2").Value Then 'it means January
    Call January
Else
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "December" Then
            ws.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ws
End If
```